# Framework 7 pages not loaded

Tags: javascript, web-applications, routes, frameworks, html-framework-7

I tried to create a web-app using Framework7 core (without node, React, Vue).

I found that clicking the tabs at the bottom of ***index.html*** the pages weren't showed.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Goiy_NOJLP3th_nEjib4pUG18J22xrVE) you can see my files (from a framework7 template).

I don't understand why they don't load dynamically.

```
  <!-- Catalog View -->
  <div id="view-catalog"  class="view view-init tab" data-view="catalog" data-url="/catalog/">
    <!-- Catalog page will be loaded here dynamically from /catalog/ route -->
  </div>

  <!-- Settings View -->
  <div id="view-settings" class="view tab">
    <!-- Settings page will be loaded here dynamically from /settings/ route -->
  </div>
```

Routes Array:

```
routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    url: '../pages/index.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/about/',
    url: '../pages/about.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/catalog/',
    componentUrl: '../pages/catalog.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/product/:id/',
    componentUrl: '../pages/product.html',
  },
......
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue in routes only, you need to change your route from this

```
  {
    path: '/catalog/',
    componentUrl: '../pages/catalog.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/product/:id/',
    componentUrl: '../pages/product.html',
  },
```

to this:

```
  {
    path: '/catalog/',
    componentUrl: './pages/catalog.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/product/:id/',
    componentUrl: './pages/product.html',
  },
```

and its will work perfect, when you using `..` you will back one step more, so that you will not find a page, by using `.` you will access web directory direct...

Comment: Solved, the problem was that the site should be hosted on a server. Thank you!

Comment: That's true, this is a basic rule for test it, but you most also change directory...dependence of your code test on server...good luck